How to log unexpected data deletions in Laravel when no explicit delete operation is called?
I'm working on a Laravel application and have encountered an issue where some data is being deleted unexpectedly, but I can't identify where the deletion is occurring. I am using the following code to retrieve some data, but at times, this data is being deleted without any explicit delete method call.
Here’s the code I’m using:
$manifest = Manifest::where('manifest_date', $manifestDate)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($selctedCity) {
        $query->whereNull('city_id')
              ->orWhere('city_id', $selctedCity);
    })
    ->whereIn('status', [1, 2])->first();

if (!empty($manifest)) {
    $deliveries = $manifest->deliveries()->orderBy('delivery_window', 'asc')->get();
} else {
    $deliveries = null;
}


However, sometimes this data is deleted, and I don't see any explicit delete operation in the code. I suspect that the data might be getting deleted elsewhere (possibly through cascading deletes, or some other query), but I'm not sure how to track it.
How can I log the deletion of data in Laravel when no explicit delete operation is called?
What are the best practices to track unexpected deletions in Laravel (e.g., model events, query logging, or database constraints)?
Is there a way to check if a delete operation is happening due to a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE?

you can just check your db schema and see if you have an unexpected ON DELETE CASCADE

Please follow this to debug issue:

Use deleting and deleted events in your model's boot method.
Activate query logging using \DB::enableQueryLog(); to track all database interactions, including deletions.
Add logs to easier tracking and understanding of the deletion event.


The 2nd and 3rd method here are great but since this is production code you (OP) might need to modify your code to e.g. add some middleware to get the query log and write it to a log stream/file at the end of each request. The 1st one is a lot more limited in what it can tell you since it only works with direct deletions on individual models
